# Hook a function on the entire backend in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to hook a function on the entire wordpress backend for a user custom role, just that when the user is accessing the edit posts page `post.php?post=xxxx0&action=edit`, the function is no more available, printed message disappears.

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'here';
    function contributor_posts() {
      echo 'here2';
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'contributor_posts' );
}
```

`echo here` - disappears - though it doesn't go on the else

`echo 'here2`- disappears also

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`admin_init` action is triggered when a logged in user access the admin area, there is no need for `is_user_logged_in()` check here.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_init

**edit:**

Put the code below inside `functions.php`, `admin_init` action **must be** triggered always in every part of the admin area. If that is not the case then i really do not know where the problem is. Visit [Wordpress Action Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) to see the list of action hooks available and the order of execution.

```
function contributor_posts() {
    echo 'here';
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'contributor_posts' );
```

Comment: Still not working. It's like `admin_init` doesn't have any effect on post.php.

Comment: Can you describe your problem a little more clearly, because, no offense, i do not understand what exactly is not working and what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I am trying to add message 'echo here' in the backend, so I created the following functon (and removed what you said -- the is_user...), but the message is not printed on the `post.php?post=24043&action=edit` admin area page/section (when you edit a post)-- in all other areas is printed.

Comment: admin_init is always triggered regardless of which part of the admin area you visit

Comment: That is the point in this case it isn't, in this particular section. Using wordpress 3.9.2

Comment: Yep, still not going for that area, i am afraid that is a bug.

Comment: Something is rotten in that Wordpress instalation ( Shakespeare )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63729/discussion-between-danijel-and-user3467855).

Comment: You can echo all you want, and it probably does show. But if the templates are generated later, it will just be replaced/redirecten. Try to put a "die" after the echo. Do you see the echo then?